# Why do I need 3 different kind of probes in kubernetes: startupProbe, readinessProbe, livenessProbe

Tags: kubernetes

Why do I need 3 different kind of probes in kubernetes:

- startupProbe
- readinessProbe
- livenessProbe

There are some questions ([k8s - livenessProbe vs readinessProbe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423405/k8s-livenessprobe-vs-readinessprobe), [Setting up a readiness, liveness or startup probe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850959/setting-up-a-readiness-liveness-or-startup-probe)) and articles about this topic. But this is not so clear:

- Why do I need 3 different kind of probes?
- What are the use cases?
- What are the best practises?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

These 3 kind of probes have 3 different use cases. That's why we need 3 kind of probes.

***Liveness Probe***

If the *Liveness Probe* fails, the pod will be restarted (read more about failureThreshold).

Use case: Restart pod, if the pod is dead.

Best practices: Only include basic checks in the liveness probe. Never include checks on connections to other services (e.g. database). The check shouldn't take too long to complete.
Always specify a **light** *Liveness Probe* to make sure that the pod will be restarted, if the pod is **really** dead.

***Startup Probe***

*Startup Probes* check, when the pod is available after startup.

Use case: Send traffic to the pod, as soon as the pod is available after startup. *Startup probes* might take longer to complete, because they are only called on initializing. They might call a warmup task (but also consider init containers for initialization). After the Startup probe succeeds, the liveliness probe is called.

Best practices: Specify a *Startup Probe*, if the pod takes a long time to start. The Startup and Liveness Probe can use the same endpoint, but the *Startup Probe* can have a less strict failure threshhold which prevents a failure on startup (s. [Kubernetes in Action](https://livebook.manning.com/book/kubernetes-in-action-second-edition/chapter-6/v-6/224)).

***Readiness Probe***

In contrast to *Startup Probes* *Readiness Probes* check, if the pod is available during the complete lifecycle.
In contrast to *Liveness Probes* only the traffic to the pod is stopped, if the *Readiness probe* fails, but there will be no restart.

Use case: Stop sending traffic to the pod, if the pod can not temporarily serve because a connection to another service (e.g. database) fails and the pod will recover later.

Best practices: Include all necessary checks including connections to vital services. Nevertheless the check shouldn't take too long to complete.
Always specify a *Readiness Probe* to make sure that the pod only gets traffic, if the pod can properly handle incoming requests.

***Documentation***

- [This article](https://medium.com/dev-genius/understanding-kubernetes-probes-5daaff67599a) explains very well the differences between the 3 kind of probes.
- The [Official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) gives a good overview about all configuration options.
- [Best practises for probes](https://srcco.de/posts/kubernetes-liveness-probes-are-dangerous.html).
- The book [Kubernetes in Action](https://livebook.manning.com/book/kubernetes-in-action) gives most detailed insights about the best practises.

Comment: What if I increased the initialdelay in liveness probe instead of using the startupProbe, while keeping the same check in both the probes.

Comment: @AmanJain Good question:  If you don't know if your applications needs 30 sec, 1 or 2 minutes to start, it would be wiser to use a startup probe. The Startup probe is executed until it succeeds before it hands over to the liveliness probes. InitialDelaySeconds on liveliness would need a predictable startup time to set as value.

Comment: What is the behaviour in case of readiness probe is failed ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow if readinessProbe fails, the container will not get any traffic. But the traffic will be routed to other containers then.

Comment: Is there any dependency between readiness and liveness probe ? Will readiness be triggered if liveness was filed ? vice versa ?

Answer (score 12):

**The difference between livenessProbe, readinessProbe, and startupProbe**

**livenessProbe**:

```
 livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

- It is used to indicate if the container has started and is alive or not i.e. proof of being avaliable.
- In the given example, if the request fails, it will restart the container.
- If not provided the default state is Success.

**readinessProbe**:

```
 readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

- It is used to indicate if the container is ready to serve traffic or not i.e.proof of being ready to use.
- It checks dependencies like database connections or other services your container is depending on to fulfill its work.
- In the given example, until the request returns Success, it won't serve any traffic(by removing the Pod’s IP address from the endpoints of all Services that match the Pod).
- Kubernetes relies on the readiness probes during rolling updates, it keeps the old container up and running until the new service declares that it is ready to take traffic.
- If not provided the default state is Success.

**startupProbe**:

```
 startupProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

- It is used to indicate if the application inside the Container has started.
- If a startup probe is provided, all other probes are disabled until the startup probe succeeds.
- In the given example, if the request fails, it will restart the container.
- Once the startup probe has succeeded once, the liveness probe takes over to provide a fast response to container deadlocks.
- If not provided the default state is Success.

Check [K8S documenation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) for more.

Comment: In startup probe you mention:
-If a startup probe is provided, all other probes are disabled.
-Once the startup probe has succeeded once, the liveness probe takes over to provide a fast response to container deadlocks.

I see contracdition between those 2 statements. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: The other probes are only disabled temporarily until the startup probe succeeds. I edited the answer to include this.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a concrete example of one we're using in our app.  It has a single crude HTTP healthcheck, accessible on `http://hostname:8080/management/health`.

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 8080
    name: web-traffic
```

### App Initialization (startup)

- Spring app that is slow to start - anywhere between **30-120** seconds.
- Don't want other probes to run until app is started.
- Check it every 10 seconds (give up after **5s**) for up to **180s** before k8s gets into a crash loop.

```
startupProbe:
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 18
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  httpGet:
    path: /management/health
    port: web-traffic
```

### Healthcheck (readiness)

- Ping the app every **10** seconds to make sure it's healthy (ie. accepting HTTP requests).
- If fail **two** subsequent pings, cordone it off (prevents cascades).
- Must pass **two** subsequent health checks before can accept traffic again.

```
readinessProbe:
  successThreshold: 2
  failureThreshold: 2
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  httpGet:
    path: /management/health
    port: web-traffic
```

### App has Died (liveliness)

- If app fails **3** consecutive health checks, **30** seconds apart, reboot the container.  Maybe app got into an unrecoverable state like Java ran out of heap memory.

```
livenessProbe:
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 3
  periodSeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  httpGet:
    path: /management/health
    port: web-traffic
```

Comment: The timings provided in this answer make the purpose of each probe so clear.

Answer (score 6):

I think the below table describes the use-cases for each.

| `Feature` | `Readiness Probe` | `Liveness Probe` | `Startup Probe` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Exmine | Indicates whether the container is ready to service requests. | Indicates whether the container is running. | Indicates whether the application within the container is started. |
| On Failure | If the readiness probe fails, the endpoints controller removes the pod's IP address from the endpoints of all services that match the pod. | If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the container is subjected to its restart policy. | If the startup probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the container is subjected to its restart policy. |
| Default Case | The default state of readiness before the initial delay is Failure. If a container does not provide a readiness probe, the default state is Success. | If a container does not provide a liveness probe, the default state is Success. | If a container does not provide a startup probe, the default state is Success. |

Sources:

- [Kubernetes in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action)

Answer (score -1):

This topic very interesting but I would like to add 1 more detail (important from my point of view).

I was not able to understand the difference between startup probe + liveness probe from one side and liveness probe with extended amount of failedTheshold.

And looks like differenceis in a nature of startup probe to be a single time executed. In contrast liveness probe and readiness probe are **cyclic** (or periodic, repeatable).

If start up probe is passed - it won't be executed until pod is alive. So the idea of startup probe to give a bit more time for application startup.

Lets consider example

```
readinessProbe:
  initialDelay: 20
  failureThreshold: 2
  periodSeconds: 10

livenessProbe:
  initialDelay: 10
  failureThreshold: 3
  periodSeconds: 5
```

We wait for 40 sec [(20 + 2*10)] startup and then 25 sec [(10 + 5*3)] for become alive but consider application is not alive after 25 [(10 + 5*3)] seconds of unavailability

Answer (score -1):

startupProbe:
Purpose: The startup probe determines whether an application within a container has successfully started and is ready to handle requests.
LivenessProbe:
Purpose: The liveness probe monitors the ongoing health of a container and determines whether it is running properly.
Readiness Probe:
Purpose: The readiness probe determines whether a container is ready to handle incoming requests and serve traffic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).